# Adding OnChange-post on droplist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do you post a form in mvc when changing the value of a droplist? do I have to add attributes or is there some inbuilt thing?

Thanks

/M

Comment: It's really best not to. You'll break keyboard selection (since every up/down keypress fires onchange) and the back button (since when returning to the page the selected option is kept, meaning you can't navigate using to the same option as no onchange will be fired).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you do something like this, nice and clean:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('mySelect').onchange = function() {
    document.forms[0].submit();
};
</script>


<form method="post">
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option>foo</option>
        <option>bar</option>
    </select>
</form>
```